# Avoid back button using vaadin

Tags: button, navigation, vaadin, back

I develop RIA application using Vaadin CDI addon. 
About the app : it has two views(viewA and viewB) which maintained by Navigator.
User story is pretty simple:

1. User enters viewA
2. Perform some business stuff
3. Redirects to viewB
4. Using address bar to go some external website(ex. google.com)
5. Press back and it goes to he lastest page what he saw(viewB), instead of viewA

Any suggestions/tips-n-tricks how to avoid redirecting to viewB, but redirect to viewA?

Vaadin Forum quiet about this thing.

Thank you

Comment: Did you use [`@PreserveOnRefresh`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.6.4/com/vaadin/annotations/PreserveOnRefresh.html) on your UI to [create an application which preserves its state on refresh](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+an+application+that+preserves+state+on+refresh), or in your particular case _when going back_?

Comment: Yes. I use it, but here's a problem refreshing viewB it automatically redirects to viewA(which is not good). I need to preserve it on pressing back button OR leaving the app (just simply closing session?)
Is it possible to specify @PreserveOnRefresh on a particular views?

Comment: `@PreserveOnRefresh` can only be used on UI classes and applies to the whole application. In this case we need to see some code as the problem could be in one of your listeners for example. It would be nice if you could share a [SSCCE](https://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjVmtij7vrLAhVDiiwKHdYxCxsQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsscce.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNFdqWH-Hxu7Vlsk6vBvl9vWtnAdrw&sig2=Kss9vXpIN_tFijEfvhg2bQ). Also when replying to comments, please use `@username` so they get notified.

Comment: @Morfic well, i'm quite sure this could be resolved in another way... Something tells me, that there can be event related to leaving UI ... unfortunate i cant remember it's name

Comment: I don't disagree, but without seeing what the code does it's close to impossible to guess what's happening.

Comment: Usually, changing views when using a `Navigator` will also change the URL. If the URL changes then your browser should notice it and that's why you're are redirected to `viewB`. You can try to subclass `NavigationStateManager` to override `setState` (I believe this is where the URL is changed -- the goal would be to avoid the URL being changed). When initializing your `Navigator`, use the constructor that takes a `NavigationStateManager` instance. I haven't tested any of this so... good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override `View.enter(...)` in your ViewB, and, according to your application state, update your view URI using `Page.getCurrent().setUriFragment(recentUrl, false);`

Comment: Good suggestion to use `enter` method, but it's took me to the right way.
1) Use `VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute()` for comparison - if that equals, then redirect. 2) [navigator usage] if you use navigator, than it's quite easier to make combine 1 and write your own class extending from ViewChangeListener.

FYI: both options requires `@PreserveOnRefresh` since we use VaadinSession
Easy to implement - first,but not so safe( requires alot of testing) as second (reliable)

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem but resolved using following code:

```
getUI().getNavigator().addViewChangeListener(new ViewChangeListener() {
                public boolean beforeViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {
                    return changeView;
                }

                @Override
                public void afterViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }});
```

Set `changeView = true` only through proper navigation's (eg: On button clicks).

This how you can avoid navigation's using browser back button. In this case if user uses any of browser buttons the view does not changes and it remains on same page.

Comment: yes, exactly how i thought. but here is the thing... once you navigate from viewA to viewB and then press back you still see viewB (which is not correct in my case) The workaround will be checking vaadinsession for a specific value upon navigation back.

Comment: if you got my idea, i got already answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781806/how-to-override-vaadin-navigator-properly and final solution ain't perfect however i managed make it working