# Customize Vaadin Navigator

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I just extended Vaadin's navigator and overriden some some methods:

```
public class MyNavigator extends Navigator {

final SpringViewProvider viewProvider;

public MyNavigator(UI ui, SingleComponentContainer container, SpringViewProvider viewProvider) {
    super(ui, container);
    this.viewProvider = viewProvider;
    addProvider(this.viewProvider);
}

@Override
public void navigateTo(String navigationState) {
    if(ViewTokens.AVAILABLE_TOKENS.contains(navigationState)) {
        if(viewProvider.getView(navigationState) == null) {
            String uriFragment = parseViewToken();
            if(uriFragment.equals(navigationState)) {
                super.navigateTo(ViewTokens.HOME);
            }
        } else {
            //if nothing found, redirect
            super.navigateTo(ViewTokens.HOME);
        }
    }
}

private String parseViewToken() {
   <ommitted>
}
```

}

This is how I set up Navigator:

```
@SpringUI(path="/")
@Theme(ValoTheme.THEME_NAME)
public class MyFancyUI extends UI {

@Autowired
SpringViewProvider viewProvider;

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    MyNavigator navigator = new MyNavigator(UI.getCurrent(), this, viewProvider);
    setNavigator(navigator);
    navigator.navigateTo(ViewTokens.SIGNIN);
}
```

}

And this is how i attempt to get navigator and redirect view to another:

```
@UIScope
@SpringView(name=ViewTokens.HOME)
public class SplashScreen extends VerticalLayout implements View {
private ComponentHelper componentHelper;
private Button toLoginPage;

public SplashScreen() {
    initComponents();
    buildSplashView();
}

protected void initComponents() {
    componentHelper = ComponentHelper.getInstance();
    toLoginPage = componentHelper.createFriendlyButton("To Login Page",220, 60);
    toLoginPage.addClickListener(this::redirect);
}

private void buildSplashView() {
    addComponent(toLoginPage);
    setComponentAlignment(toLoginPage, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    setHeight(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
}

public void redirect(Button.ClickEvent event) {
    getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(ViewTokens.SIGNIN);
}

@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent viewChangeEvent){

} 
}
```

And for some reason, button doesn't react to click event.

Replacing to standard Navigator - it works.

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: You should check out the view change listener. You won't need to override navigator. I would post some code but I'm not near my computer today.

Comment: @ChrisM Sounds interesting, i'll stay tuned.

Comment: There's also the SpringNavigator class, which includes SpringViewProvider.

Comment: @nyg thanks, but thats not a case where does it should be used. Anyway i wrote my concept.

Comment: My personal research did not so good but, the getUI().getNavigator() returns instance of com.vaadin.Navigator, which leads to quite possible solution... extend UI and override getNavigator method in order to get MyNavigator.

Comment: @ChrisM unfortunately, this is quite essential to make MyNavigator, since 80% of logic rely on thats overridden methods.

Comment: There's maybe an issue with your navigateTo method. If viewProvider.getView is not null meaning a view is found, you tell your navigator to go to the home view.

Comment: @nyg well, i'm sure that with SpringViewProvider works correctly, because it loads correctly and navigates to ViewToken.SIGNIN. If i'm going to idea to use standard navigator, then i have to somehow make checks for navigating(view exists or not) and etc...

Comment: I will be appreciated, if someone could provide example how to do it (if possible) or how to do it in "smarter way than this"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought that you could use Vaadin's Navigator and a View Change Listener like this:

```
        navigator.addViewChangeListener(new ViewChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean beforeViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {
            // check you're happy to change

            if (ViewTokens.AVAILABLE_TOKENS.contains(navigationState)) {
                if (viewProvider.getView(event.getViewName()) == null) {
                    String uriFragment = parseViewToken();
                    if (uriFragment.equals(event.getViewName())) {
                        navigator.navigateTo(ViewTokens.HOME);
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    // if nothing found, redirect
                    navigator.navigateTo(ViewTokens.HOME);
                    return false;
                }
                // Let the view change happen.
                return true;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {

        }
    });
```

If you return false in the beforeViewChange it will stop the view change from happening.

Comment: is that suppose to be specified in every view, that i use or what?

Comment: No you add this to your navigator when you create it. I've made an error which I'll change in a second.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! Thanks, in concerns of clean code ( i want to make UI.init() cleaner as possible) what if i want to make own implementation of ViewChangeListener, then how do i get navigation state from navigator?(if that is possible)

Comment: You could easily have a separate class to implement ViewChangeListener. You would then only need navigator.addViewChangeListener(new YourViewChangeListener());